# SQLite select records from last 24 hour

Tags: php, sqlite

I have this struct of data stored in an SQLite DB:

[image: stored datas]

I'm trying to get the records from the past 24 hours in a php code.

I use the following query that I found at similar questions:

```
SELECT temp FROM Sysstat 
WHERE when >= date('now', '-1 days') AND when < date('now')
```

But it doesn't seem to work and gives error:

> Warning: SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, near "when": syntax error in..

Anyone could give me some advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enquote `when` with `"` or `[]` or backticks:

```
SELECT temp 
FROM Sysstat 
WHERE "when" >= date('now', '-1 days') AND "when" < date('now');
```

[SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

> The list of keywords is so long that few people can remember them all. **For most SQL code, your safest bet is to never use any English language word as the name of a user-defined object.**
>
> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it.
>
> "keyword"     A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier.
>
> 121. WHEN

Comment: Thanks, now it runs without errors but returns 0 record. All the records are stored 'today', could it be a problem?

Comment: @sOnt `date('now')` => `2017-10-29 00:00:00` All your records are after midnight.